# Shiny interactive plotting with selected likert scale

Tags: shiny

I have created several likert scales with R package "likert" and would like to plot each one of them in shiny when the radio button of that one is selected.
The sample scales is:

```
a <- sample(rep((1:5),5))
b <- sample(rep((1:5),5))
c <- data.frame(sapply(data.frame(a), factor))
d <- data.frame(sapply(data.frame(b), factor))
scaledc <- likert(c)
scaledd <- likert(d)
```

The shiny codes are:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Survey"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("type",
                  "Plot Type",
                  choices = c("Likert"="bar",
                              "Density"="density",
                              "Heatmap"="heat"), selected="Likert"),
      radioButtons("qtype", 
                    "Question type:",
                    c("Agreement"="scaledc", "Helpfulness"="scaledd"),
                selected="scaledc")
  ),


# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Yearly Data", plotOutput("distPlot1"))
      )
    )
  )
)



#server
server <- function(input, output) {  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({plot(input$qtype, type=input$type)+
      ggtitle("How agree are you with following statements?")}, height = 1000)

}
```

The shiny returned error "need finite 'ylim' values." I think it's becaue the input$qtype doesn't pass the correct information to the plot command, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you for advance!

Comment: The code you provide is not a standalone reproducible example. Please add enough code to make it easy to run. I did notice that the plot call is going to try and plot "aggScaled" and "bar" which will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved the problem.
The missing codes in server are:

```
  scale <- reactive({
   get(input$qtype)
})
  output$dat <- renderPrint({
   scale()
})
```

And then do plot with scale() will show selected plot.